# Use of windowHandles within Nightwatch Page Objects

Tags: javascript, function, nightwatch.js

I am using Nightwatch JS page objects to create my tests.  When clicking on a link that opens a new tab, I cannot switch focus to the new tab.

Any other searches haven't used windowHandles within the page objects.

```
var verifyHomepage = {
    verifyPrivacy: function () {
        return this.waitForElementVisible('body', 20000)
            .click('@privacyLink')
            .windowHandles(function (result) {
                var handle = result.value[1];
                this.switchWindow(handle);
            })
        .waitForElementVisible('body', 20000)
        .assert.urlContains('/regression/en-us/PrivacyStatement')
        .assert.containsText('@privacyHeader', 'Privacy Statement');
    }
};


module.exports = {
    commands: [verifyHomepage],
    url: function () {
        return this.api.launchUrl;
    },

    elements: {
        // Fill in the empty quotes with your selectors
        header: '#customBlock > div > h1',
        login: '#loginBtn',
        homeLogo: '#siteLogo',
        footerLogo: '#siteLogoFooter',
        homeLink: '#footerBtnHome > a',
        privacyLink: '#footerPrivacyStatment > a',
        privacyHeader: '#mainBlock > div > h1'
    }
};
```

this.waitForElementVisible(...).click(...).windowHandles is not a function

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the issue you're running into is that the `.windowHandles` command requires the `this.api` instead of just `this`, and since it's being called within the `.waitForElementVisible` callback function, it inherits `this`. So, one thing you could try is to put the `.windowHandles` command inside of a `.click` callback function like so:

```
var verifyHomepage = {
    verifyPrivacy: function () {
        return this.waitForElementVisible('body', 20000)
            .click('@privacyLink', function () {
                this.api.windowHandles(function (result) {
                var handle = result.value[1];
                this.switchWindow(handle, function () {
                    this.waitForElementVisible('body', 20000)
                    .assert.urlContains('/regression/en-us/PrivacyStatement')
                    .assert.containsText('@privacyHeader', 'Privacy Statement');
               });
            })
        })  
    }
};
```

I also recommend moving the commands running against the new page into the `.switchWindow` callback like I show, since you may run into issues with them trying to reference the original window handle otherwise.